# How to connect Python Selenium actions to Robotframework test suite

Tags: python, robotframework

I'm trying to perform a webpage Title check through a custom Python script in Robotframework.

Problem is that even if title has "https" in it, the test is returned as "PASS" in robotframework log: it seems like the script is not linked to the correct driver session or something like that.

I'm sure there's a lot of errors so if you could help me it would be highly appreciated.

Here's the python code:

```
from robot.api import logger
from SeleniumLibrary import SeleniumLibrary
from SeleniumLibrary.base import keyword
from SeleniumLibrary.keywords import BrowserManagementKeywords
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from robot.libraries.BuiltIn import BuiltIn


class  title_check(SeleniumLibrary):

    @keyword('test_keyword')
    def title_checker(self):
        selib = BuiltIn().get_library_instance('SeleniumLibrary')
        driver = selib._current_browser()

        self.assertNotIn("https", driver.title)
```

and here's robotframework keyword:

```
   check title
       Title_checker.test_keyword
```

Comment: Is this _really_ your code? You explicitly create a new instance of the driver, yet in the following line you are using `driver` rather than `self.driver`. I don't see why you don't get an error when you run this code. You also haven't defined a keyword named `keyword` even though you are trying to use  a keyword with that name.

Comment: Hi @BryanOakley Sorry for pasting such a bad code, that's why I'm asking for help. Any tip would be highly appreciated. 
Regarding opening a new istance of the driver, I tried many times to figure how to connect to the one robot framework opened and that's part of my question.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand the reason behind this Python code. I would do this directly in RF:

```
Title Checker
    Open Browser     ....
    ${title} =     Get Title
    Should Not Contain    ${title}    https
```

Comment: thanks, this is a very good solution which I was ignoring. :-)